# PHP form post to database

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

So, i've googled and everything for more than a week by now but i cannot get this fixed.

I have a form with specific stuff. I would like for the user to be able to fill in this form. Then click on the button Submit, and for the filled in form to be posted into my database.

I've been trying and trying every possible way but this just isn't working for me, so hopefully someone here can help me.

The code i have thus far (my form):

```
<div class="regForm">
<h1> Register here: </h1>
    <form method='POST' action='connectie.php' id="registerPage">
        Username:<br>
        <input type="text" name="username" size="20"><br>
        Password:<br>
        <input type="text" name="password" size="20"><br>
        First name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" size="20"><br>
        Last name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" size="20"><br>
        Age:<br>
        <input type="text" name="age" size="20"><br><br>
        E-mail adress:<br>
        <input type="text" name="mail" size="20"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="register" id="regButton" value="Register">

<h1> Unsubscribe here: </h1>
        Username<br>
        <input type="text" size="20"><br>
        Password<br>
        <input type="text" size="20"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="unsub" id="unsubButton" value="Unsubscribe">
    </form>
</div>
```

And my connection to the database (local on wamp)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$fname =  $_POST['first_name'];
$lname = $_POST['last_name'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$email = $_POST['mail'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (`ID`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `password`, `age`, `email`) VALUES (NULL, '$fname', '$lname', '$username', '$password', '$email', '$age');";
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'studie');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'i268296_studie');
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
// Check connection
$connection_error = $connection->connect_error;
if ($connection_error != null) {
    echo "Error connecting to database: $connection_error";
    exit();
}
$result = $connection->query($sql);
?>
```

So, if someone could be so kind to point me in the right direction how i can Submit the text from the form into my database. The unsubscribe stuff doesn't need to work right now. Hopefully someone can help me because PHP in combination with the database is slowly driving me mad :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Define "isn't working."  In what way does it fail?  Do you get any errors (even in the PHP and/or web server logs)?  Where specifically does the code fail?  Also, that looks like a SQL injection vulnerability.  You might want to start reading about that: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: @David well, at this moment the second i go to the connection.php (with the queries etc. in it) It just fills in a empy cell in the database, but it should only put a new row/cell in the database if i press the submit button. So basically i need to attach the submit button to the form (when pressed, put the filled in items from the form into the database). I don't get any errors etc. But the different codes i've tried with google just don't seem to work. And i really don't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your comment:

> at this moment the second i go to the connection.php (with the queries etc. in it) It just fills in a empy cell in the database

It sounds like the PHP code and the HTML form are both on the same page (`connectie.php`)?  What's happening in this case is that you're executing the server-side code *before* displaying the form.  Note that when you request a page, any server-side code on that page is going to be executed.  The PHP code doesn't really know or care about forms or buttons, it's just going to run whatever code is in that file.

You have two options:

1. Separate the code which *presents* the form from the code which *processes* the form into two different pages.  One page can just be plain HTML to show the form (maybe with some minimal PHP code if you want to do some server-side work to show the form).  The second page (the one referenced in the form's `action` attribute) would then have the PHP code for receiving the form inputs.  That way the code to handle the form is only invoked when the form is actually submitted, not when it's requested.
2. Wrap your form-handling server-side code in something like:

   `if (isset($_POST['register'])) { /* process registration code */ }`

This second option will conditionally invoke the logic in that `if` block only when a form has been submitted with a `register` element (the name of one of your buttons).  You can do the same with the logic for the `unsub` button.  The idea here is that when you *request* the page, these `if` conditions are `false` and don't execute.  But when you submit the form, one of them is `true` and does execute.

---

Also, and ***this is important***:

1. You have a SQL injection vulnerability in your code which allows any user to *execute their code* on your server.  Please refer to [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) for more information on how to protect your code from this.
2. Your code is storing user passwords in plain text.  ***Never store user passwords in plain text.***  Passwords should be hashed with a 1-way hash and should never be readable by anybody.

Comment: At this moment i have the Connectie.php (which is the second block of code) seperated from the form (which is in registration.php) and on top i include the connectie.php:
<?php
 session_start();
 include 'connectie.php';
?>

I think that your second option might work for me. But the code, it should work when pressing on submit like it is right? (i just need to put it in the if statement)

Comment: It works with the if statement, it now puts whatever i fill in, into the database on submit. Much love man! thanks!! i knew it would be something simple...

Comment: @Xereoth: It's separated into its own file, but if you're *including* it in the first page then it's still being executed.  By separating it I mean that it should be its own page.

Comment: @Xereoth: Also, I've added a couple of ***important*** notes to my answer.  Please take them seriously, as they directly impact your users.

Comment: Yeah, that was my next step, to make the passwords secure/unreadable. I will read up on the SQL injection vulnerability. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Put your connection code before all the $_POST row..

You make a query BEFORE connect the database...so, how you can do the query if there aren't connections? and also, like first php code, write session_start();

```
<?php
session_Start();

//YOUR CODE
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'studie');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'i268296_studie');
$connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

**WHEN THE CONNECTION IS SET, YOU CAN DO YOUR QUERY**

```
$fname =  $_POST['first_name'];
$lname = $_POST['last_name'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$email = $_POST['mail'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (`ID`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `password`, `age`, `email`) VALUES (NULL, '$fname', '$lname', '$username', '$password', '$email', '$age')";
ADD $result=mysql_query($sql);

//YOU OTHER CODE..
?>
```

this is the code that I used in my site for the connection to the database for a login (change the query for your insert)..

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $host=""; // Host name 
    $username=""; // Mysql username 
    $password=""; // Mysql password 
    $db_name=""; // Database name 
    $tbl_name=""; // Table name 

    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    //take datas from inputs
   $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
   $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
   $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
   $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE BINARY U_NomeUtente='$myusername' and U_Password='$mypassword'"; 
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count==1) //if the login it's ok
        {

            header("location:pagethatyouwantoreach after the login.php"); 
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: 1) You're mixing `mysqli` with `mysql`.  2) This code is *wide open* to SQL injection.

Comment: 1) can you please tell me where is mysqli in my code? I'm a beginner in php too so I'm happy to learn ^^

Comment: First code block, last line.  (Ctrl-F is helpful for finding text in the web browser.)  Everything else in the answer is `mysql`, even though the OP is clearly using `mysqli`.  You've also gone on to add *more* SQL injection vulnerabilities.  The code you've posted shouldn't be used in any production system at all.

Comment: about 1) the first block is the code from Xereoth that I  used in my answer, not mine ^^ But I should have noticed and change it, you're right...
(only last block is mine)
about 2) I added stripslashes & mysql_real_escape_string but I'm note sure that are enough for the sql injection problem..I'm trying to improve the code, but I'm beginner

Comment: That use of `mysql_real_escape_string` may *coincidentally* work in any case you've encountered, but take a look at its documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php  That read box near the top of the page indicates the deprecated status of the functionality and provides links to better alternatives.